# How to start transaction with /dsd/ code in SAP easy access?

Tags: jscript, sap-gui

How can I start transaction in SAP easy access using jScript with code which contains `/dsd/`, like `/DSD/DE_ENTRY`? In other cases it seems like

```
session.StartTransaction("VT01N");
```

But it won't work with `/dsd/` tCodes.

Comment: Do you get an error message?

Comment: No, code like
`session.StartTransaction("/DSD/DE_ENTRY");`
just ignored

Comment: Could you please try `session.StartTransaction("/n/DSD/DE_ENTRY");`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you appear to be remote-controlling the SAP GUI client, you have to specify the transaction code as you would in the GUI: `session.StartTransaction("/n/DSD/DE_ENTRY");`